# simple FIFO stack (queue) for MoveIt in ROS

Tags: ros, moveit, queue, stack, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use a simple queue (FIFO stack) to give a list of waypoints to MoveIt. I looked at the tutorial : [Callbacks_and_Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) and the class [CallbackQueue](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1CallbackQueue.html) but it looks like we can use it only with Publisher/Subscriber.
Is there any existing simple queue or must I create it from array?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204616/simple-fifo-stack-(queue)-for-moveit-in-ros/) by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'd better use

std::queue
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/

or
std::list
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/
with push_front() and pop_back()

The problem with std::vector in this use case is that it will have to relocate your entire data every time you call  insert( name_vector.begin(),element)  in order for keeping its memory layout. This might be computationally expensive! For std::vector you can only efficiently insert / remove objects at the end of the vector.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on 2015-03-31**:
Ok, thanks!